# facebook php sdk 4.0.0

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I can't get user id with facebook php sdk :|. Anyone can help me ? this is the code.
I spend like 4 hours to get some results but nothing. with sdk 3.2.3 works fine but with 4 i can't get it to work.

```
<?php
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

 // init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('','');



 $helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
// When validation fails or other local issues  
}
if ($session) {
try {

$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();

} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

 }   

 // Logged in.
```

}

Comment: Is it giving you a specific error that you could share with us?

Comment: no  error...just not working

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You have to go [to your facebook developer panel](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) and generate an access token for this app by clicking "You need to grant permissions to your app to get an access token."

Then your code should be something like this:

```
$session = new FacebookSession('your-token');

try {
  $me = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
  echo $me->getName();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
  // The Graph API returned an error
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Some other error occurred
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is just not well initiated with your app ID and Secret.
But you can no more get the real user id with the new graph api and php sdk.
Read [their changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) for details